# Twitter-Bootstrap and Forms in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap

This may be a beginners question but not having much luck getting this going.  The background:

1. Rails 3.0.x version
2. Bootstrap 2.0 - using as pre-compiled simply placed into public/stylesheets.
   Att
3. Attempting to do a form with horizontal layout, i.e. label next to the input field on the same line.

The issue is that I can't get the form to work, but can get the default Bootstrap sample code, in the same form to layout correctly.  The Rails form looks like:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span4 well">
    <%= form_for @member, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"} do |m| %>
        <fieldset>

          <%= m.label :title  %>
          <%= m.text_field :title %>   

          <%= m.label :first_name %>
          <%= m.text_field :first_name %>
    <% end %>
   </div>
</div>
```

Notice that the **form_for** method has the class of *form-horizontal* as described by in [Bootsrap form CSS](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms)

When displayed the label, for example title, is on one line left adjusted and then on the next line is the input field, also left adjusted.

Now if I include some of the sample Bootstrap code for forms such as:

```
<div>
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Legend text</legend>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="input01">Text input</label>

        <div class="controls">
          <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="input01">

          <p class="help-block">Supporting help text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Then I get the expected outcome -- label and input field on the same line in horizontal layout.

I've tried adding the style "control-label" onto the m.label and m.text_field components but no joy in getting the layout as horizontal.

Thus, not sure what the issue is, since the working part validates that I can get Bootstrap to work, although with my Rails Form it's not honouring the form-horizontal.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to do the form vanilla (as in, without simpleform-bootstrap or other gems), you need to shape the form HTML accordingly:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span4 well">
    <%= form_for @member, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"} do |m| %>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Member Form</legend>
          <div class="control-group">
            <%= m.label :title, :class => "control-label" %>
            <div class="controls">
              <%= m.text_field :title, :class => "input-xlarge" %>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-actions">
            <%= m.submit :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

As Arun Kumar Arjunan says, the form builder is not generating the html needed for the bootstrap framework.

Definitely check out the HTML needed in the [bootstrap example pages](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms), and/or by inspecting the DOM (i found that it's not really well documented). All in all, you can do it manually, like above, by creating your own [form builder](http://railscasts.com/episodes/311-form-builders), or by using various gems.

Also as a sidenote, make sure to check out [how to customize the errors css](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#customizing-error-messages-css), because by default, when a validation error occurs, the field is wrapped by a `<div class ="field_with_errors">` breaking the css selectors used by bootstrap.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the field helpers are not generating the proper html for twitter bootstrap.

You can use simple_form gem which supports twitter bootstrap. See the documentation:

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

Here is the example application: https://github.com/rafaelfranca/simple_form-bootstrap

Live Demo: http://simple-form-bootstrap.plataformatec.com.br/

Comment: Thanks - Curious that I still see the HTML and appropriate CSS classes on the generated HTML when using the Bootstrap attributes on the form.

Answer (score 3):

I've found Stephen Potenza's bootstrap-form gem to be incredibly helpful (and easy to use). Add the gem to your gemfile, and use 'bootstrap_form_for' where you would use 'form_for':

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Enter your name" %>
  <%= f.text_field :email, placeholder: "Enter your email" %><br>
  <%= f.password_field :password, placeholder: "Enter a password" %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, hide_label: true, placeholder: "Confirm password" %>
<%= f.submit "Sign Up" %>
<% end %>
```

Makes the whole thing a breeze.

https://github.com/potenza/bootstrap_form

Answer (score 2):

Another approach that might be a bit simpler:

In your `views/<model>/edit.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for(@<model>, :html => {:class => 'form form-container'}) do |f| %>
<%= f.error_messages %>

<%= render '<model>/form',:f=>f %><% end %>
```

Then, create a file like this `views/<model>/_form.html.erb` which will contain your Bootstrap-enabled form fields, i.e.:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label(:name) %>
  <%= f.text_field(:name, class: "form-control") %>
</div>
```